# Perfect Participle - "Having gained truth, keep truth"

Tags: grammar, participles, participial-phrases

"Having gained truth, grab the truth"

This is an example of the Exercise in Grammar 51 in Wren and Martin, which actually asks for the noun being qualified by the partciple beside its type.

Now, two things are clear:
1: "Having gained" is an active perfect participle,
2: And, the first instance.of "truth" is the object of the participle, as it is telling the some thing has gained the truth.

So, "truth" can't be the noun qualified by the participle as the qualified noun is a sort of subject, weather in active mood or passive mood. So, the first thing crossed my mind when I read the example that it qualifies "you" implied in "grab", an imperative.

But, surprisingly, the key of Wren and Martin mentions "truth" as the noun being qualified by the participle.

So, if someone kindly elaborate where lies the problem: in my understanding or in the key![image]

Comment: Their answer is quite puzzling. *Truth* is the direct object of both verbs. I would have thought, as you did, that they also both shared the same subject as well.